# Print Image with jquery dont work

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hy Guys...

i have some lightbox script where i can build custom buttons. I've maked one buttom to print an image showed in the lightbox.. but the image don't apear on print window (tested in Google Chrome, Firefox an IE8)... here my

my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery("#getdropdown").change(function() {
        var trial=jQuery("#getdropdown option:selected").val();
        
        jQuery.lightbox(trial,{
              buttons: [
                {
                  'class'     : 'botao-imprimir',
                  'html'      : 'IMPRIMIR',
                  'callback'  : function(url) {
                    title = window.open(trial);
                    //title.document.write(trial);
                    title.print();
                  }
                }
              ]
            });     
        
    });
});
</script>
```

and Here is my HTML:

```
<select name="getdropdown" class="drop-receitas" id="getdropdown">
    <option value="">Escolha aqui a receita desejada</option>
    <option value="receitas/image.jpg">Image</option>
    <option value="receitas/image2.jpg">Image 2</option>    
</select>
```

on `var trial` i have the image, and when i select some option on my list, it's shows the image with the button "IMPRIMIR" (Print).. What i'm doing wrong?

Ty for help!

EDIT: [Here](http://www.alsite.com.br/graodebico/receitas1.asp) is the link with the problem. Click in some item on DropDown

Comment: i checked in my chrom 15.0 , image perfectly appeared

Comment: Is the image set as a background image? They get printed by default, though there is an option in the browser to enable it.

Comment: @Jon - no.. the image is not set as background.... the image is the option value of dropdown list: `<option value="images\someimagehere.jpg">Some Name Here</option>`

@sandeep - my chrome version is 17.0 - but i have tested in Firefox and IE 8 and i can't print the image. Do you can?

Comment: **CORRECTION:** I only can print in IE - on Chrome and Firefox still can't print the image!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should open a window object to an HTML page which contains the image in an  tag.
Something like this:

```
jQuery.lightbox(trial, {
  buttons: [
    {
      'class'     : 'botao-imprimir',
      'html'      : 'IMPRIMIR',
      'callback'  : function(url) {
        var imgWindow = window.open('', 'popup', 'toolbar=no,menubar=no,width=imageWidth,height=imageheight');
        imgWindow.document.open();
        imgWindow.document.write("<html><head></head><body onload='window.print()'><img src='"+url+"' /></body></html>");
        imgWindow.document.close();
       }
     }
   ]
 });
```

Another way of doing it is using a print stylesheet, which hides everyting else, than the image. Take a look here: http://www.webcredible.co.uk/user-friendly-resources/css/print-stylesheet.shtml (First Google hit).

Comment: thanks.. working in all browsers now!! I dont know i need to open entire HTML. I'he tested only with the image tag and works great!